# Algebraic structure- associative property proof

Tags: linear-algebra

We will define an algebraic structure in the following way:
$(\mathbb {N} ,*)$
$a*b=a+b-1$
And i have to prove associative property,i thought of doing it the following way:
$(a+b)-1=a+(b-1)$
$(a+b)=x,(b-1)=y$
$x-1=a+y$
$x-y=a+1$
$a+1=a+1$
But I'm not sure that's enough

Comment: The associative property for the structure $(\mathbb N,*)$ is the statement that $(x*y)*z=x*(y*z)$ for all $x,y,z\in\mathbb N$.

Answer (score 2):

Let $ (a,b,c)\in \Bbb N$.

$$(a*b)\color{red}{*}c=(a*b)+c-1$$
$$=(a+b-1)+c-1=a+b+c-2$$

on the other hand

$$a\color{red}{*}(b*c)=a+(b*c)-1$$
$$=a+(b+c-1)-1=a+b+c-2$$

Can you conclude ?

Comment: Thanks everyone, now it's clear.

Comment: @NFLX You are Welcome.

Answer (score 2):

In order to prove associative property, you need to show $$ (a*b)*c = a*(b*c)$$

Note that $$ (a*b)*c = (a*b)+c-1= (a+b-1)+c-1 = a+b+c-2$$

Also $$ a*(b*c)= a+(b*c)-1 = a+(b+c-1)-1 = a+b+c-2$$

Thus the operation is associative.